# Cycle Through Javascript Vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**~~~SOLVED~~~**

***Thanks for help from the community I just rewrote my question maker to automatically just make an array and I can confirm after doing that and referencing my array everything works perfectly!***

**~~~End Solution~~~**

I am back again with I am sure another simple solution that after hours of coding can't find! lol. So my javascript is as follows:

```
function startgame() {
  var x = 999;
  var qquesnum = 1;
  var qquesval = ('q' + qquesnum + 'question');
  for (var qgs=1; qgs <= tq; qgs++) {
    $("body").append('<div id="q' + (qgs) + '" class="question" style="z-index: ' + x + ';"><h2 class="questionnum">Question ' + (qgs) + '</h2><br /><p class="question' + (qgs) + '"></p><input type="button" onclick="cycleremove()" value="Done" class="removebutton"></div>');
    x = (x-1);
    qquesnum = (qquesnum + 1);
  };
  $('.file').toggle();
  $('.question').toggle();
};
```

The file in which the user uploads and the div is created has a whole list of vars such as:

```
var q#question = "{Question Data Here}";
```

where as the "#" is a real number such as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc...

The script at the top is executed after the user uploads the file to the website so the var's are already defined. I just can not figure out how to exactly get the var q#question to show up in between the paragraph tags and cycle all the way through the q#question variables.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an array?

Comment: In Javascript, the only scope that you can iterate a list of `var` declared variables is the global scope.  Javascript does not contain a means to iterate variables defined within a function scope.  The usual solutions are to declare the data in an array or as properties of an object.  Both of those can then be iterated.

Comment: Did not think about using an array, I guess I just got so caught up with appending that it would make "sense" to try to do it with '("q" . qgs . "question")'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`, however, using `eval` is almost never a good idea. If you can, rewrite your game to use an array of question objects instead.

```
for (var qgs=1; qgs <= tq; qgs++) {
    var qquesval = eval('q' + qgs + 'question');
    // your append code
}
```

Comment: I rewrote my whole question maker to push to an array and I can confirm this does work!